# how to store json data in php use json_decode and for

Tags: php

I wrote a plugin for my site that is Ripley plugin
But when you copy the text to a user, it will be displayed as a code in the history
like this

```
{"action":"reply","umsg":"hi","uname":"admin","mymsg":"helo"}
```

The code I put in the history file is like this:

```
    $jmsg = str_replace(array('<b>', '</b>', '<i>', '</i>'), '', $row['7']);
    if (isJson($jmsg)) {
        $jd = json_decode($jmsg, true);
        if (isset($jd['action'])) {
            $replymsg = $jd['umsg'];
            $replyme = $jd['uname'];
            $mymsg = $jd['mymsg'];
            if ($jd['action'] == 'reply') {
                if ($color == 'D5D5D7') {
                    $color = 'EEEEFF';
                } else {
                    $color = 'D5D5D7';
                }
                echo "<msg><![CDATA[<tr id=\"msg-{$row['id']}\" bgcolor=\"#{$color}\"><td width=\"50\" align=\"center\">{$row['id']}{$delmsg}</td><td width=\"180\" align=\"center\">{$row['username']}</td><td width=\"80\" align=\"center\">" . jdate::start('Y/m/d H:i:s', $row['date']) . "</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"direction : rtl;word-break: break-all;max-width: 100px;font-family:{$row['fontname']};font-size:{$row['fontsize']}px;\"><div class=\"pmbox\"><div class=\"mess_back\"><div id=\"repbox\"><div id=\"khat\"><div id=\"name\">{$replyme}</div><div id=\"text\">{$replymsg}</div></div><div id=\"means\">{$mymsg}</div></div></div></div></td><td width=\"80\" align=\"center\">{$room}</td></tr>]]></msg>";
            }
            if ($jd['action'] == 'delete') {
                continue;
            }
            if ($jd['action'] == 'reply') {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($color == 'D5D5D7') {
        $color = 'EEEEFF';
    } else {
        $color = 'D5D5D7';
    }
    echo "<msg><![CDATA[<tr id=\"msg-{$row['id']}\" bgcolor=\"#{$color}\"><td width=\"50\" align=\"center\">{$row['id']}{$delmsg}</td><td width=\"180\" align=\"center\">{$row['username']}</td><td width=\"80\" align=\"center\">" . jdate::start('Y/m/d H:i:s', $row['date']) . "</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"direction : rtl;word-break: break-all;max-width: 100px;font-family:{$row['fontname']};font-size:{$row['fontsize']}px;\">{$row['text']}</td><td width=\"80\" align=\"center\">{$room}</td></tr>]]></msg>";
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in the above code that displays the data like that.

Comment: Are you sure `isJson()` is returning `true`? That's not a standard PHP function.

Comment: The source code of this plugin is running and can be replicated by users only in the history as an exponential code